# .Net WinForms - Remove Close, Resize and Minimize Button

Tags: c#, winforms, autoresize, window-resize, minimize

My application layout is defined with a top menu and a content area below.

In the content area I use to load the action form in a panel by adding them as a control.

First question is: is it ok as approach?

Second question: Now the forms are loaded in the content panel with Maximize, Resize and Minimize Button. How can I remove them?

Thanks

Comment: First question is: Subjective. Second question: Really unclear. Please clarify your questions with some screenshots if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Change your form's border style to none.  Those "forms" should probably be UserControls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your Form `ControlBox` property to False.

See: [Form.ControlBox Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

To set it in the designer, go to form properties and set `ControlBox` to false.

[image]

This is how it would look after that:

[image]

For your first question:

> is it ok as approach?

That depends on your requirement. As long as you have provided your user a way to exit from the application and it is easily accessible, it should be fine, IMO.